# Grails, tagLib g:remoteLink does not exist

Tags: grails, gsp, taglib

I'm trying to add a delete-button to my edit-form but have not found anything that work and when I found that remoteLink could help me I tried that but when adding it to any form/app I always get:

> "Tag [remoteLink] does not exist. "

I'm using Grails-3.2.4.
Maybe I need to import something or..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `remote*` tags were deprecated and removed in Grails 3.x. You should be using javascript library for making AJAX-calls

Comment: Hmm.. would have saved me some time if it had been better documented. However, I finally found it on an older grails-doc but not when I searched for missing taglib remoteLink.

Answer (score 0):

This taglib and code was placed as external plugin. You can add it via
additional dependency in build.gradle:

```
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:ajax-tags:1.0.0'
```

plugin page: https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/ajax-tags